# How can I apply ContainerRequestFilter without web.xml?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty, servlet-filters

I'm currently making a RESTapi using jersey 2.27 and jetty 9.4.
In this server I'm trying to apply a filter:

```
@AuthenticationEndpoint.Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String REALM = "example";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Bearer";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        //Authentication code
    }

    private boolean isTokenBasedAuthentication(String authorizationHeader) {

    }

    private void abortWithUnauthorized(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {


    }

    private void validateToken(String token) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

However, this filter isn't triggered.

This is my endpoint:

```
@Path("/authenticate")
public class AuthenticationEndpoint {

    Machine machine = Machine.getInstance();

    @NameBinding
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({TYPE, METHOD})
    public @interface Secured { }



    @POST
    @Path("/authenticate")
    @Secured
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response authenticateUser(
            AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest){

    }
```

I don't have a web.xml and I wouldn't know how to actually get this filter to trigger. Anyone have some advice for this? I'm having a hard time understanding this server filter configuration.
PS: i left out the content of the methods since I thought it would be too chaotic, I will of course add it if it is deemed necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the filter when you create the Application, something like

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
  register(AuthenticationFilter.class)
  // yada yada
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what class that would be in my case. The one where I create and run the server in?

Comment: You have a class somewhere for registering the `AuthenticationEndpoint` class?

Comment: Yes 
 servletHolder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", AuthenticationEndpoint.class.getCanonicalName());